# Capture image from configuration activity of widget

Tags: image, configuration, widget, capture, onactivityresult

I have created a **widget** and in **configuration activity** I want take a picture with **camera** so I create my intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

And also `onActivityResult`

And *Camera permission* is *guaranted*

When I take a picture and click `OK` my configuration activity is **finish**. I don't get any result or error, what could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: More information is needed. Add details on how to reproduce the problem. Snippets of code would help as well.

Comment: How you get and process the result you got ? post more code.